# how do I get update notification from server to client?

Tags: java, sql

Hi I am doing a task using socket programming,in this I have database on server side and whenver any employee update any table ,server should notify all employee by triggring pop up on employee pc.my question is how to get any update from server and how to trigger pop up on server notifivation.plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

Databases are poll-only, so you can't do this through the database.  "whenever any employee update any table" - this happens through the server, no?  The server needs to, when this happens, update the database and then send a message out after the database update is complete.  This can be done through the open sockets to the clients through a protocol you define.

Answer (score 0):

How many clients are we talking about?  There are multiple ways of doing this, polling as was mentioned, is one that would be simple for a limited number of clients.  It doesn't scale but would suffice for a small number of users.

Your problem is a classic pubsub issue that could be solved by various pubsub mechanisms.  XMPP based pubsub, for example, using any one of a number of XMPP servers ([OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp), [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/), ...) and writing your client code, including publishing trigger, with [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp).